# Where is run() implemented in twisted?

Tags: python, twisted

This is a question about how to refer to twisted API documentation.

I use twisted to write a simple server program with python like this,

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
reactor.listenTCP(8000, server.facotry)
reactor.run()
```

This program worked well, but I wondered the definition of run() in class reactor, then I referred to twisted API documentation.
And I wrote in the code

```
import inspect
inspect.getmembers(reactor)
```

Then, I got

```
('run', <bound method SelectReactor.run of <twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor object at 0x0000000002C68F60>>)
```

I guessed run() in twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor.
But I didn't find run() in [twisted.internet.selectreactor.py](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-15.2.1/twisted/internet/selectreactor.py#L55%20).

Where is the definition of run()?

Comment: `SelectReactor` has a two base classes. [`posixbase.PosixReactorBase`](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-15.2.1/twisted/internet/posixbase.py#L265) is derived from [`ReactorBase`](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-15.2.1/twisted/internet/base.py#L437) and also [`_SignalReactorMixin`](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-15.2.1/twisted/internet/base.py#L1123), which defines [`run`](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-15.2.1/twisted/internet/base.py#L1192)

Comment: Is there Python's command to display where a function is defined?